# Material UI MobileStepper background color change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uistepper

Hoping someone can assist. I am using the MobileStepper component, specifically:

https://mui.com/api/mobile-stepper/

and attempting to use a different background color for this stepper. Looking at the Dev Tools for this component, I found the following:

```
.MuiMobileStepper-root {
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fafafa;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I actually just want to change the background value to:

```
.MuiMobileStepper-root {
    background: #dadada;
}
```

Unsure how to change this within my React component.

Not sure if it's an overrides/root style change?

Comment: You can use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content): e.g.`sx={{bgcolor: '#dadada'}}`

Comment: @tromgy - I tried that as follows but didn't work: `<MobileStepper sx={{bgcolor: '#dadada'}} variant="text" ......`

Comment: In this case please create a reproducible example. Or you can use this working demo [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobilestepper-bgcolor-qlzq3) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
<MobileStepper sx={{ bgcolor: 'transparent' }}/>
```